# Solr search quality improve

Tags: solr

I have two document like:

```
<doc>
    <field name="title">I love world cup</field>
</doc>
<doc>
    <field name="title">I love basketball</field>
</doc>
```

when I input query keyword"I love world cup" I only expect the first doc, but get two results.

```
"docs": [
      {
        "id": "p11112",
        "title": "I love world cup",
        "_version_": 1472408699840495600
      },
      {
        "id": "p11111",
        "title": "I love basketball",
        "_version_": 1472408682961567700
      }
     ]
```

how to find only include like "world cup" document?

Answer (score 0):

This is a term query:

```
?q=title:i love world cup
```

It will match both documents because Solr interprets the query like this:

```
?q=title:i OR love OR world OR cup
```

You can instead use `AND` to only match documents that contain all terms in the query:

```
?q=title:i AND love AND world AND cup
```

If you alway want to use `AND` between terms, and you don't want to enter them manually, you can make `AND` the default for a query using the `q.op` parameter:

```
?q=title:i love world cup&q.op=AND
```

An alternative would be to use a phrase query, which will only match if the entire phrase (delimited by the double quotes) exists in the document:

```
?q=title:"i love world cup"
```